# Unify and simplify MySQL commands

Tags: mysql, sql

I did some MySQL commands, however it was a bit slow to execute because there are three commands executed at the same time.

How can I unite all in just one command and simplify the code to make it faster?

```
UPDATE bidbutler b
    LEFT JOIN auction a on b.auc_id=a.auctionID
    LEFT JOIN auc_due_table c on b.auc_id=c.auction_id
    SET b.butler_status=0
    WHERE b.auc_id=a.auctionID
    AND b.auc_id=c.auction_id
    AND b.butler_status<>0
    AND a.auc_status=3
    AND c.auc_due_price<>a.auc_final_price
    AND c.auc_due_time=a.total_time;

DELETE t1
    FROM won_auctions t1
    LEFT JOIN auc_due_table t2 ON t1.auction_id = t2.auction_id
    LEFT JOIN auction t3 ON t1.auction_id = t3.auctionID
    WHERE t1.auction_id = t2.auction_id
    AND t1.auction_id = t3.auctionID
    AND t2.auc_due_price<>t3.auc_final_price
    AND t2.auc_due_time=t3.total_time
    AND t3.auc_status=3;

UPDATE auction a
    LEFT JOIN auc_due_table b on a.auctionID=b.auction_id
    SET a.auc_status=2
    WHERE a.auc_status=3
    AND a.auctionID=a.auctionID
    AND b.auc_due_price<>a.auc_final_price
    AND b.auc_due_time=a.total_time;
```

The three commands will be executed at the same time through a database procedure, which is executed every second by an event.

NEW DELETE UPDATED:

```
DELETE t1
    FROM won_auctions t1
    JOIN auction t2
        ON t1.auction_id = t2.auctionID
    LEFT JOIN auc_due_table t3
        ON t3.auction_id = t1.auction_id
        AND t3.auction_id = t2.auctionID
        AND t3.auc_due_price<>t2.auc_final_price
        AND t3.auc_due_time=t2.total_time
    WHERE t2.auc_status=3;
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your system architecture if you are running the same stored procedure every second.  You probably want triggers.

Comment: I don't think the slowness is due to three separate statements. It's not possible to combine the `DELETE` statement with an `UPDATE` statement. SQL doesn't work like that. We notice predicates in the WHERE clause require non-NULL values for `b` and `c`. That effectively negates the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN. I'd recommend removing the extraneous LEFT keyword. It looks like the statements have the potential to churn through a lot of rows, even with appropriate indexes defined. Use EXPLAIN to see the execution plan, and ensure suitable indexes are being used,

Comment: @spencer7593...In fact until today I could not understand the difference of using `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`. And in the case of `UPDATE` it is possible to run in a single command?

Comment: @GordonLinoff...No, I already have a trigger, but I need to execute these commands after the trigger has been triggered, so I'll run along with an existing procedure.

Comment: `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are referred to as *statements*, not *commands*. It might be possible to combine the two `UPDATE` statements, if the second `UPDATE` statement is not dependent on the results of the preceding `UPDATE` and/or `DELETE` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**preamble**

*repeating notes I left as a comment on the question, because I'm not sure there was enough emphasis placed on these points:*

"I don't think the slowness is due to three separate statements."

"It looks like the statements have the potential to churn through a lot of rows, even with appropriate indexes defined."

"Use EXPLAIN to see the execution plan, and ensure suitable indexes are being used, ..."

---

**answer**

The `DELETE` statement can't be combined with an `UPDATE` statement. SQL doesn't work like that.

It might be possible to combine the two `UPDATE` statements, if those are visiting the same rows, and the conditions are the same, and the second `UPDATE` is not dependent on the preceding `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statement.

We see the first `UPDATE` statement requires a matching row from `bidbutler` table. The second `UPDATE` statement has no such requirement.

We notice that the predicates in the `WHERE` clause are negating the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN. If the original statements are correctly implemented (and are performing the required operation), then we can eliminate the `LEFT` keyword.)

We also find a condition `a.auctionID=a.auctionID` which boils down to `a.auctionID IS NOT NULL`. We already have other conditions that require `a.auctionID` to be non-NULL. (Why is that condition included in the statement?)

We also see a condition repeated: `b.auc_id=c.auction_id` appearing in both the `ON` clause and the `WHERE` clause. That condition only needs to be specified once. (Why is it written like that? Maybe something else was intended?)

The first `UPDATE` statement could be rewritten into the equivalent:

```
UPDATE auction a
  JOIN auc_due_table d 
    ON d.auction_id     = a.auctionID 
   AND d.auc_due_time   = a.total_time
   AND d.auc_due_price <> a.auc_final_price

  LEFT
  JOIN bidbutler b
    ON b.auc_id         = a.auctionID
   AND b.auc_id         = d.auction_id
   AND b.butler_status <> 0        

   SET b.butler_status  = 0
 WHERE a.auc_status     = 3
```

The second `UPDATE` statement can be rewritten into an equivalent:

```
UPDATE auction a
  JOIN auc_due_table d 
    ON d.auction_id     = a.auctionID
   AND d.auc_due_time   = a.total_time
   AND d.auc_due_price <> a.auc_final_price

   SET a.auc_status     = 2
 WHERE a.auc_status     = 3
```

The difference is the extra outer join to `bidbutler` table, and the `SET` clause.

But before we combine these, we need to decipher whether the operations performed in the first `UPDATE` or the `DELETE` statement) influence the second `UPDATE` statement. (If we run these statements in a different order, do we get a different outcome?)

A simple example to illustrate the type of dependency we're trying to uncover:

```
UPDATE foo  SET foo.bar = 1  WHERE foo.bar = 0; 
DELETE foo.*  FROM foo       WHERE foo.bar = 0; 
UPDATE foo  SET foo.qux = 2  WHERE foo.bar = 1;
```

In the example, we see that the outcome is (potentially) dependent on the order the statements are executed. The first `UPDATE` statement will modify the rows that won't be removed by the `DELETE`. If we were to run the `DELETE` first, that would remove rows that would have been updated... the order the statements are executed influence the result.

Back to the original statements in the question. We see `auc_status` column being set, but also a condition on the same column.

If there are no dependencies between the statements, then we could re-write the two `UPDATE` statements into a single statement:

```
UPDATE auction a
  JOIN auc_due_table d 
    ON d.auction_id     = a.auctionID 
   AND d.auc_due_time   = a.total_time
   AND d.auc_due_price <> a.auc_final_price

  LEFT
  JOIN bidbutler b
    ON b.auc_id         = a.auctionID
   AND b.auc_id         = d.auction_id
   AND b.butler_status <> 0        

  SET b.butler_status   = 0
    , a.auc_status      = 2 

 WHERE a.auc_status     = 3
```

---

Comment: Great answer, so in fact it should run the **DELETE** first, then the **UPDATE** of the `bidbutler` table and finally the **UPDATE** of the `auction`, exactly in that order.How would that be? The two updates do not need any information from the table that will be deleted by DELETE, so it can be executed by first. The problem is to invert the UPDATE, because the update of the `bidbutler` table depends on `auc_status = 3`, and the second update changes its status to: `auc_status = 2`

Comment: And in the case of DELETE there is how to simplify in the same way that was done in the UPDATE?

Comment: I updated the question, you can check if I did the DELETE in the correct way, how would you do? I tried to follow the UPDATE pattern.

Comment: For the rewritten DELETE, i'd remove the outer join to `auc_due_table`. (I'm not sure how smart the optimizer is. But we can see that it's not going to matter if any matching  rows are found in `t3`. it's going to remove rows from `t1` whether are zero matching rows or a million matching rows in `t3`. (The `LEFT` keyword indicates this is an *outer* join. If we are intending an *inner* join, remove the keyword `LEFT`. (The only specification is the SQL statements in the question. And it's not at all clear to me that these statements are actually doing exactly what they were intended to do.)